# Use of ratio in ImageWMS in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, wms, clip, image

I am trying to understand the setting of `ratio` in `ol.source.ImageWMS` but I am not succeeding. I already understand the `ratio: 1`, as there is not much to understand there. `ratio: 1` = browser viewbox. I also understand the principle of `ratio: 2`.

> Ratio. 1 means image requests are the size of the map viewport, 2
> means twice the width and height of the map viewport, and so on. Must
> be 1 or higher.

The Data of a `BBOX` is sent in the URL-querystring at the server request. But it seems that these are not the coordinates of the BBOX from the ratio. Or is it? If no, then I ask how the data of the ratio BBOX can be calculated?

What I need is the data for cropping. So far I had no success to calculate them.

This calculation does not provide the correct data for cropping:

```
var ImageWMS_ratio = 2; // range 1 - 2

var mapsize_width = map.getSize()[0];
var mapsize_height = map.getSize()[1];

var mapsize_width_ratio = (mapsize_width * (ImageWMS_ratio - 1));
var mapsize_height_ratio = (mapsize_height * (ImageWMS_ratio - 1));

/*
// In this example without if() rules.
// The if() rules are calculated with the BBOX data from the URL-Querystring and map.getPixelFromCoordinate([]);
// If a Image edge outside the BBOX, then cropping, otherwise = 0.
*/
var left_crop = (mapsize_width_ratio * -1);
var bottom_crop = (mapsize_height + mapsize_height_ratio);
var right_crop = (mapsize_width + mapsize_width_ratio);
var top_crop = (mapsize_height_ratio * -1);
```

Note: For all those who think that the WMS calculates this: No WMS is used. The cropping data is needed.

Here are three graphics that clarify the whole thing. I visualized it with a `ratio greater than 1` and in 3 zoom levels.
Picture 1: The image is inside the browser viewbox.
Picture 2: The image is outside the browser viewbox and inside the ratio BBOX (i think).
Picture 3: The image is outside the browser viewbox and outside the ratio BBOX (i think). Cropping is necessary.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you further clarify what you want to achieve, looking at your third example, is it that you've made a GetMap request, it has returned an image (that fits  the green box) and then in OpenLayers you want to remove part of that image (the red bit)?

Comment: @nmtoken, the first, i will understand it. I have a PHP script that delivers a scaled and/or croped image. It works fine with `ratio:1`, but had problems with ratio greater 1, also already without cropping. I don't understand the logic of ratio greater 1. First also i will understand it for coding a calculation. Last, i need the data, to scale and crop the images correctly. I don't use a WMS. The BBOX data for the images and there names are in a array in the Javascript code. In the `ol.source.ImageWMS` i can use the `imageLoadFunction` for calculation the data and send it to the server.

Comment: I'm confused by the statement `No WMS is used.`  Does your PHP script provide an OGC [Web Map Service (WMS) interface](https://www.ogc.org/standards/wms) or not?

Comment: My PHP script does'nt OGC or similar. It is very simple. Look here: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/13675 . I send the required data with the `imageLoadFunction` and use the existing URL-query keys:values.

Comment: I removed the tag wms, which is specific to the OGC WMS specification.  I guess you're in uncharted territory now, OpenLayers ImageWMS is expecting an OGC WMS but you're not using one

Comment: @nmtoken, and how does that help me to understand the ratio on ImageWMS? It is a WMS.

Comment: It helps avoid confusion that you are talking about an OGC Web Map Service.   Instead of a bespoke service created by you that provides maps as a web service.